# Vine VNC server at login

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I've been trying to run Vine system server on 10.7.x and 10.8.x so that I can login while no one is using the remote computer. As a connection is made I do get the login screen and the mouse works (I'm able to click restart, shutdown, etc). Unfortunately when I start typing the password in the text field to login in, the image freezes. Funny though that the mouse is still usable.

After looking at the logs I, these are the errors that pop out to me:

```
OSXvnc-server[104]: 3891612: (connectAndCheck) Untrusted apps are not allowed to connect to or launch Window Server before login.
OSXvnc-server[104]: Window Server is not available
```

I searched the vine forums and looks like this issue was supposed to be solved with the 4.01 release which I'm using. And unfortunately the forums are proving to be a dead end.

I've googled this with no luck. Even started playing with Vines keyboard and hardware settings. Any help or a nudge in a certain direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.7 and 10.8 include a built-in VNC server. This server will likely work better than the VINE edition while viewing the Login Window.

You can [enable the built-in VNC server](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-08-03-setting-up-the-vnc-server-in-mac-os-x-10-7-aka-lion/) through the **System Preferences > Sharing** settings.

[image: Enable VNC on Mac OS X 10.7]

Comment: 100% correct. Forgot to mention at the time that built-in OSX VNC was  a no go. But your post is good to let others know of the built in option.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you mark the answer as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work